# Rotation around an edge (A newbie question)

Tags: transforms

Is it possible in Blender 2.8 to rotate an object (or a vertex group) around an edge? The edge then serving as an axis of rotation. If so, how is it done?

Comment: Could you add an image to demonstrate the effect you want?

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it!